# MapViewOfFile returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER Windows-10(Universal Windows Platform)

Tags: windows, file-io, memory-mapped-files, windows-10-universal

I am trying to port my existing  Windows desktop application (runs fine on Windows-7) to Windows-10 (Universal Windows Platform)

On Windows-10, MapViewOfFile returns

> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

,when I set access type to `FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE`.
 My code below:

```
   HANDLE mhandle = NULL;
   HANDLE g_hfile;
   LARGE_INTEGER ms_size;
   size_t file_size = 0;     
   void* map = NULL; 

   CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS ms_param;
   ms_param.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
   ms_param.dwFileAttributes = GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE;
   ms_param.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
   ms_param.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_DELEGATION;
   ms_param.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
   ms_param.hTemplateFile = NULL;
   g_hfile = CreateFile2(filename, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_EXISTING, &ms_param);
   if (g_hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       return GetLastError();
   }

   if (GetFileSizeEx(g_hfile, &ms_size) == 0)
   {
       return GetLastError();
   }

   file_size = ms_size.u.LowPart | ((unsigned long long)ms_size.u.HighPart << 32 );
   mhandle = CreateFileMapping(g_hfile, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, (unsigned long long)ms_size.u.HighPart, ms_size.u.LowPart, NULL);
   if (mhandle == NULL)
   {
       return GetLastError();
   }

   map = MapViewOfFile(mhandle, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE, 0, 0, file_size);
  if (map == NULL)
  {
     return GetLastError();
  }
```

File being mapped is of size approximately 1KB. If I set access type to `FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE` or `FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_EXEC` `MapViewOfFile` works as expected.
But if I use either FILE_MAP_READ | `FILE_MAP_EXEC | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE` or `FILE_MAP_EXEC | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE` `MapViewOfFile` fails.

I didn't find any Windows-10 specific documentation for this api. I have read the available MSDN doc for this api here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx

Moreover, API set for UWP doesnt seem to contain this api:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186421(v=vs.85).aspx

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: The linked documentation for MapViewOfFile says "desktop apps only".

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the response. I am trying to port my Windows desktop app to UWP

Comment: It seems unsurprising that UWP apps are unable to create executable memory regions.  That would make it trivial to escape the sandbox.  (The only surprising part is that, contrary to the documentation, you can use MapViewOfFile at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is not relevant anymore, but hope my answer will be helpful for those who face same issue. You are using correct UWP API for file creation, but API for file mapping is wrong. You need to use [CreateFileMappingFromApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingfromapp) instead `CreateFileMapping` and [MapViewOfFileFromApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffilefromapp) instead `MapViewOfFile`. Take a look carefully, PageProtection type for UWP `CreateFileMappingFromApp` doesn't allow EXECUTE at all.

Here the code example, with plenty of comments describing non obvious fragments:

```c++
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// you may combine access in the same was as pageFileAccessMode allows
enum class AccessMode {
    READ,
    READ_WRITE
};

DWORD openFileForMapping(AccessMode accessMode, std::wstring const & filepath, HANDLE * fileHandler, std::size_t & fileSize, HANDLE * fileMappingHandler) {
    DWORD fileAccessRegularMode;
    DWORD fileAccessSharedMode;
    DWORD pageFileAccessMode;
    HANDLE localFileHandler;
    HANDLE localFileMappingHandler;

    switch (accessMode) {
    case AccessMode::READ:
        fileAccessRegularMode = GENERIC_READ;
        fileAccessSharedMode = FILE_SHARE_READ;
        pageFileAccessMode = PAGE_READONLY;
        break;
    case AccessMode::READ_WRITE:
        fileAccessRegularMode = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
        fileAccessSharedMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
        pageFileAccessMode = PAGE_READWRITE;
        break;
    }

    // parameters MUST be initialized with zero and size
    CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS createFile2ParametersEx{ 0 };
    createFile2ParametersEx.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
    createFile2ParametersEx.dwFileAttributes = fileAccessRegularMode;
    // parameters options, depends on your requirements
    createFile2ParametersEx.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
    createFile2ParametersEx.lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
    createFile2ParametersEx.hTemplateFile = NULL;

    localFileHandler = CreateFile2(filepath.c_str(), fileAccessRegularMode, fileAccessSharedMode, OPEN_EXISTING, &createFile2ParametersEx);
    if (localFileHandler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER msSize;
    if (GetFileSizeEx(localFileHandler, &msSize) == 0) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    fileSize = msSize.QuadPart;
    localFileMappingHandler = CreateFileMappingFromApp(localFileHandler, NULL, pageFileAccessMode, fileSize, NULL);
    if (localFileMappingHandler == nullptr) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    *fileHandler = localFileHandler;
    *fileMappingHandler = localFileMappingHandler;
    return S_OK;
}

DWORD getView(AccessMode accessMode, HANDLE fileMappingHandler, std::uint64_t beginIndex, std::uint64_t lengthOfView, void ** mapView) {
    DWORD mapViewAccessMode;

    switch (accessMode) {
    case AccessMode::READ:
        mapViewAccessMode = FILE_MAP_READ;
        break;
    case AccessMode::READ_WRITE:
        mapViewAccessMode = FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE;
        break;
    }

    *mapView = MapViewOfFileFromApp(fileMappingHandler, mapViewAccessMode, beginIndex, lengthOfView);
    if (*mapView == nullptr) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    return S_OK;
}

DWORD getFileMapViewAndPrint() {
    DWORD errorCode;
    // don't forget, UWP app have write access only inside container local folder
    std::wstring filename = L"test.txt";

    // open file with desired acces and create file mapping 
    HANDLE fileHandle;
    HANDLE fileMappingHandle;
    std::size_t fileSize;
    errorCode = openFileForMapping(AccessMode::READ, filename.c_str(), &fileHandle, fileSize, &fileMappingHandle);
    if (errorCode != S_OK) {
        return errorCode;
    }

    // using created file mapping project map view to file
    void * mapView;
    errorCode = getView(AccessMode::READ, fileMappingHandle, 0, fileSize, &mapView);
    if (errorCode != S_OK) {
        return errorCode;
    }

    // mapView now contains row data from file, in my case it was txt
    // with UTF8 text so I just need to cast void to char
    OutputDebugStringA(static_cast<char*>(mapView));
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");

    // cleanup
    UnmapViewOfFile(mapView);
    mapView = nullptr;
    CloseHandle(fileMappingHandle);
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return S_OK;
}
```